# How come Flash does not register a keypress on my computer, but on other computers it does?

Tags: flash, keypress

Ok so I have the following issue... I'm writing a code for a game and right now I've just been working on character animation. Right now what it does is it moves sideways with Left and Right, with Up it flies, and with space it shoots. The animation is working perfectly fine, for example, I can move to the right, fly and shoot at the same time with no issues, but when I try to do this to the left, I can only seem to get two keys to activate: for example, I can move to the left and fly, but when I press Space it does not answer; I can move to the left and shoot, but when I press Up it does not fly; I can fly and shoot when looking to the left, but if I press left it does not move... Now apparently there is nothing wrong with the code, because apparently when I run my .swf on other computers with flash it seems to run fine. So I would just like to know if anyone knows what could be causing this issue on my computer... Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

i am pretty sure that this is because you are "testing" the movie (ctrl+enter compiler) and special keys such as up, down, left, right, ctrl, space, enter, etc are being captured by the flash IDE itself.

if you run the same swf file outside of the flash IDE it will work on your computer as well.

if you want to be able to capture those keypresses from the IDE as well, simply: click the "control" menu (when testing the movie) and then click "disable keyboard shortcuts"